# Are there any linux drivers for msi graphics cards?

Tags: mining

I'm trying to setup my machine to mine. Not real concerned about return, just trying it out and would like to support the network that way.

Have an msi n760 graphics card (is it okay to post a link to it on newegg? don't want to post an unwelcome link) that I'd like to use but I don't believe I have the proper drivers for it to mine with. Unfortunately graphics card mining is not my specialty, so any help or point in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an nVidia driver for linux that will support the GTX 760, which covers your graphics card. Here is one such driver, though newer drivers likely also work:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.32-driver

I would guess that mining with that card might be okay from an income perspective, but the electricity costs will probably also be high.

This post would seem to get you started on how to actually mine on linux:

https://steemit.com/monero/@mobidick/how-to-mine-monero-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-ccminer-cryptonight